# Increase container max-width with media query for +1500px screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For devices with width greater than `1500px`, I want the container to have its `max-width` as `1440px` (Bootstrap4 default `max-width` here is `1140px`). I found several answers on stackoverflow which do work for Bootstap 3, but can't get it to work in BS4, such as using a simple media query like the following:

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}

*/ @media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1440px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- css: bootstrap 4 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- css: main -->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>This is a stupid headline<br/>with a short text hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1 class="text-left">Right Side Test with left align</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from the red frame and developer console, the max width is still at 1140px despite the viewport width being +2000px.

[image: 2000px resolution]

What am I missing?

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: how else should I illustrate the result in the browser/developer console?

Comment: Copy the contents of the console and post it as text.

Comment: ok. any comment on possible solution?